# Is "Clean Graph" a Thing?

Tags: graphs, terminology

My professor uses the term "clean graph" to mean that the nodes have no idea of the topology. Each node is aware of its ID, but has no idea about parents or edges and so on and it has to discover.

Is this terminology a thing? Because I find no evidence in the internet. Is there another term for the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried asking your professor?

Comment: Sounds like the implied context is networking. I guess 'clean' refers to initial state of network. Like what you would informally call a new array with all cells filled with default value such as 0 a clean array. That is, I think it's just make sense informally.